# Load a Resource file to an array in Visual Basic?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have gotten to the point in making a game where I need to figure out how I do load the levels.

So if I had a resource file called "level0" and its contents would be something like this:

```
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000200000003
1111111111111111
16
160
```

How I would load them to a 16x12 array?

Also, I need to load the player's start coordinates as well. In this case, they would be 16 and 160.

EDIT:

The resource file is a text file.

Comment: What type is the resource file? Text / Byte[] ?

Comment: Is it a project resource or an external file which the project does not have reference to? I will post the code accordingly.

Comment: The file is in the project itself.

Comment: Ok, please wait for just a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code:

```
Dim levelDataRaw As String() = (My.Resources.level0).Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
Dim levelData16x12(12) As String
For i As Integer = 0 To 11
    levelData16x12(i) = levelDataRaw(i)
Next
Dim startCoordinates(2) As String
startCoordinates(0) = levelDataRaw(12)
startCoordinates(1) = levelDataRaw(13)
```

So, you can access the data by row and then by column, i.e, to get the third digit of the second line, use:

```
levelData16x12(1)(2) 'For 2nd line, (2-1) or 1 and for 3rd digit, (3-1) or 2.
```

Just in case you don't know (please don't think I consider you a newbie) : Because indices are zero-based, be sure to subtract 1 from both positions as I have done in the code.

To access the coordinates:

```
startCoordinates(0) '16
startCoordinates(1) '160
```

I hope this helps :)

**Update** - To use external files, just replace `My.Resources.level0` with `File.ReadAllText("level0.txt") like this:

```
Dim levelDataRaw As String() = File.ReadAllText("level0.txt").Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None) 'Or some other filename instead of [level0.txt]
```